# How to restrict state in angularjs $state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Can someone help me, im stucked from this problem

I want to restrict the user on what page they have to access.
The only thing i know is that i use resolve in $state to do this
but i can't redirect the user to 401 page for example if they visit a page that are restricted ..

here is my $state config

```
   .state('app.libraries.class', {
        url: '/class',
        data: { pageTitle: 'Class Library' },
        templateUrl: 'views/libraries/class.html',
        resolve: {
            access: ['$q','AccessService', function($q,AccessService){
                var currentUser = AccessService.currentUser();
                if(currentUser.hasAccess === "false"){
                    return $q.reject('unauthorized!');
                }

            }]
        }
    })
    .state('app.libraries.account', {
        url: '/account',
        data: { pageTitle: 'Account Library' },
        templateUrl: 'views/libraries/account.html',
        resolve: {
            access: ['$q','AccessService', function($q,AccessService){
                var currentUser = AccessService.currentUser();
                if(currentUser.hasAccess === "false"){
                    return $q.reject('unauthorized!');
                }

            }]
        }
    })
```

Here is my $stateChangeError

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams,
fromState, fromParams, error) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('app.dashboard.index');
});
```

What supposed to be the problem? I just getting this error

Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 6, message: The transition errored, 
   detail: unauthorized!)

Comment: what version of ui-router are you using ?

Comment: I used 1.0.3
. hmm i'm stucked

Comment: Then i guess it's because the event isn't fired, check my answer for a potential solution. I ran across this problem recently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using ui-router 1.0.3 i guess you're problem is that stateChange events are not fired anymore.

In their doc :

> NOTE: State change events are deprecated, DISABLED and replaced by Transition Hooks as of version 1.0

Now you're supposed to use Transition Hooks, check this link : https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events

You could replace your `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError, ...` with something like this :

```
app.run(function($transitions,$state) {
  $transitions.onError({ }, function(trans) {
     $state.go('app.dashboard.index');
  });
})
```

Also have a look at this : https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#onerror

It should help you

Comment: Thanks :)
Solved my problem